# How to parse Nullable<DateTime> from a SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, t-sql

The DateTime.TryParse method takes a DateTime as an argument, not a DateTime? ?

Right now I have the following code:

```
if(!DateTime.TryParse(reader["Placed"].ToString(), out _placed)){
    throw new Exception("Order's placed datetime could not be parsed.");
}
```

where _placed is of type

```
Nullable<DateTime> _placed = null;
```

What's a way around that?

Comment: Is the `Placed` column actually a string in the db? If not then what is it?

Comment: No, Placed is a DateTime field. Should I be using the reader's ["Placed"] return value directly?

Comment: Yes. See Dylan's answer for how to do it.

Comment: For DataReader extension method see this Q (near duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489960/nullable-datetime-with-sqldatareader

Answer (score 22, accepted):

How about this instead:

```
int x = reader.GetOrdinal("Placed");

if(!reader.IsDBNull(x))
    _placed = reader.GetDateTime(x);
```

Comment: +1. Or, if `_placed` needs to be assigned in either case: `_placed = reader.IsDBNull(x) ? (DateTime?)null : reader.GetDateTime(x);`

Answer (score 7):

Just a combination of top answer and top comment.  Thanks @Dylan-Meador and @LukeH.
(Ed. Note: For the long tail I think this version will save plenty of human time.)

```
int x = reader.GetOrdinal("Placed");
DateTime? _placed = reader.IsDBNull(x) ? (DateTime?)null : reader.GetDateTime(x);
```

Comment: It's really a pity that in this age ADO doesn't have a built-in nullable DateTime helper.

Answer (score 5):

And here is @yzorg 's answer turned into a reusable extension method

```
public static class SqlDataReaderExtensions
{
    public static DateTime? GetNullableDateTime(this SqlDataReader reader, string fieldName)
    {
        int x = reader.GetOrdinal(fieldName);
        return reader.IsDBNull(x) ? (DateTime?) null : reader.GetDateTime(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime? _placed  = null;
DateTime d2;
bool isDate = DateTime.TryParse(reader["Placed"].ToString(), out d2);
if (isDate) _placed  = d2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `IsDBNull` method of the reader to determine if the value is null prior to trying to parse a date out of it.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal. The out argument is not set if the parse fail. So if the type of the wargument were Nullable it would have been a redudant information.