# Nullable DateTime with SQLDataReader

Tags: c#, asp.net

I almost hate to ask this question seems like it has been asked a million times before but even with me researching the other question I still cant seem to figure this out in my case.

I read that DateTime is a nullable type and I tried a few of the examples but I am trying to figure out if it is NULL in the database my SQLDATAREADER is failing.

**Error**

> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot 'be called on Null values.'

**DetailsClass**

```
private DateTime? startingDate;

public DateTime? StartingDate
{
    get{ return startingDate; }
    set{ startingDate = value; }
}

// constructor
Public DetailsClass(DateTime? startingDate)
{
    this.startingDate = startingDate;
}
```

**DBClass**

```
   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {

                List<DetailsClass> details = new List<DetailsClass>();
                DetailsClass dtl;
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.CommandText = "Stored Procedure Name";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyParameter", myparameter);

                    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            dtl = new DetailsClass((
                                reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("MEMBERSHIPGEN"))),
                                reader.IsDBNull(1) ? null : reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("EMAIL")),
                                reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("STARTINGDATE")));


                            details.Add(dtl);
                        }
                        reader.Close();
                        return details;

                    }
                }
```

Comment: "I read that DateTime is a nullable type" - you read wrong. `DateTime` is not nullable, `DateTime?` is.

Comment: I understand what you are saying now I just left the question mark out

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Here is a helper method to get the value out from the reader

```
public static class ReaderExtensions {

  public static DateTime? GetNullableDateTime(this SqlDataReader reader, string name){ 
       var col = reader.GetOrdinal(name);
       return reader.IsDBNull(col) ? 
                   (DateTime?)null :
                   (DateTime?)reader.GetDateTime(col);
  }
}
```

**Update on how to use in response to comment**

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {

            List<DetailsClass> details = new List<DetailsClass>();
            DetailsClass dtl;
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = "Stored Procedure Name";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyParameter", myparameter);

                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        dtl = new DetailsClass((
                            reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("MEMBERSHIPGEN"))),
                            reader.IsDBNull(1) ? null : reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("EMAIL")),
                            reader.GetNullableDateTime("STARTINGDATE"));


                        details.Add(dtl);
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                    return details;

                }
            }
```

Also note you are using `reader.IsDBNull(1)` and then `reader.GetOrdinal`.  Probably should be `reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("EMAIL"))`

Comment: .IsDbNull is throwing an exception saying System.Data.Sqlclient.Sqldatareader does not contain a definition for isdbnull any idea

Comment: @Jay Because I made a typo, it should be `IsDBNull`, answer now corrected

Comment: Im loosing it cant believe i missed that... thanks for your help one more question you have a ; to end the statement after ("STARTINGDATE"); but i need to put a , so i can add more columns to the reader and if you look at my code I am not assigning startdatetime = to the reader anywhere how would i implement it this way.

Comment: @Jay answer updated, also see the comment about the end about your code for the email read...

Comment: Bob thanks with your helper method and abhitalks answer i was able to get this working wow never thought getting a null datetime value out of the database would be so challenging

Comment: Thanks again i marked yours as correct based on the last update THanks everyone for the help this was a mission

Comment: HI I had same issue this worked a treat +1. I added a col version  public static DateTime? GetNullableDateTime(this SqlDataReader reader, int name)
        {
            var col =name;
            return reader.IsDBNull(col) ?
                        (DateTime?) null:
                        (DateTime?)reader.GetDateTime(col);
        }

Comment: @Ggalla1779, if you added a column version then you should change the name version to read `GetNullableDateTime(this SqlDataReader reader, string name) { return reader.GetNullableDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal(name));}` to prevent repeating yourself

Comment: well I have 2 signatures 1 with int other with string for name so would I change the string signature / method

Answer (score 4):

replace

```
DateTime startingDate;
```

with

```
DateTime? startingDate;
```

The question mark marks it as a nullable value and your reader should be able to set startingdate to null instead of throwing an exception.

you could also check for null values while your reader is working and replace null values with empty strings

```
while(reader.read())
{
  //column is an int value of your column. I.e: if the column ist the 8th column, set column to 7 (0-based)
  StartingDate = (reader.IsDBNull(column)) ? null : reader.GetOrdinal("STARTINGDATE"));
 //instead of null you could also return a specific date like 1.1.1900 or String.Empty
}
```

Comment: I edited my code based on your suggestion however still throwing the same error. And I know it is this field causing the error cause when I place a value in the database it populates fine.

Comment: This code is wrong: reader.GetOrdinal gets the integer index of the named field "STARTINGDATE", so why are you assigning it to a DateTime field?

Comment: details.StartingDate = reader.IsDBNull(15) ? null : reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("STARTINGDATE"));  Recieving no implicit conversion null and system.datetime

Answer (score 4):

I know this question has been answered, but further simplifying the code to deal with other nullable variable type. The answer above only limits to one specific variable type. The nice thing about this is that it also allows you to include a default value rather than setting it as null.

```
public static T GetDataType<T>( this SqlDataReader r, string name, object def = null )
{
     var col = r.GetOrdinal(name);
     return r.IsDBNull(col) ? (T)def : (T)r[name];
}
```

then in the code, you can use such as

```
...
while(reader.Read())
{
    data1Bool = reader.GetDataType<bool?>("data1"); // if it's null then we'll set it as null
    data2intNotNull = reader.GetDataType<int>("data2", 0); // if the data is null, then we'll set to 0
    data3date = reader.GetDataType<DateTime?>("data3", DateTime.Now); // same example as above, but instead of setting to 0, I can default it to today's date.
}
...
```

I had other issue regarding of null-able value object, and this saved me hours of trying to figure out what's going on. (WPF doesn't explain the issue when compiling runtime.)

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. Please edit your answer.

Comment: Thank you, I revised my code. Let me know if there's anything else I can further improve on.

Comment: This code is what I was looking for, and it is exquisite.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please tell us exactly which line is throwing the error while debugging. It would be easier.

```
if (! reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("STARTINGDATE"))) {
    obj.startingDate = reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("STARTINGDATE"));
}
```

no need to explicitly assign null if it is DBNull, because it is a nullable type so by default it will contain null.

Ok, as per your updated code (note the comments):

```
while (reader.Read()) {
    dtl = new DetailsClass((reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("MEMBERSHIPGEN"))),

    // here you are checking null for email
    reader.IsDBNull(1) ? null : reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("EMAIL")),

    // here you are not checking null for startingdate ?
    reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("STARTINGDATE")));
    details.Add(dtl);
}
```

Lets try it in more verbose way:

```
while (reader.Read()) {

    dtl = new DetailsClass();

    dtl.membershipgen = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("MEMBERSHIPGEN")) ? null : reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("MEMBERSHIPGEN"));
    dtl.email = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("EMAIL")) ? null : reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("EMAIL")),
    dtl.startingdate = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("STARTINGDATE")) ? null : reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("STARTINGDATE")));

    details.Add(dtl);
}
```

Comment: It is a list collection so when i debug it highlights my whole collection and says the above error i posted but after doing so messing around once i put a value in the startingdate column in the database everything works so I know it is the starting date line in my sqldatareader

Comment: @abhitalks you need to cast your null as `DateTime?` otherwise you will get a cast exception out of the compiler.

Comment: Is it possible to give 2 people the answer?

Comment: @Bob Oh yes. Coming from a VB world :)

Comment: @Jay No problems. Your problem is solved, that's more important.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Make the `startingDate` variable `nullable`, like this:

```
DateTime? startingDate;
```

Now, when retrieving the value from the `SqlDataReader` object you need to use the `IsDbNull` method, which will determine if the value is `NULL` coming back from the database, like this:

```
if !reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("STARTINGDATE"))
{
    startingDate = reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("STARTINGDATE"));
}
else
{
    startingDate = null;
}
```

Note: I am not sure where you are assigning `startingDate` to the value read from the database, because it is not shown in the posted code. That is why I assigned it directly in my example, but you may need to adjust the placement of the example logic.

Comment: Thanks for the response to place this code directly in the reader and what is MiddleName?

Comment: I will post my code how it is exactly so you can see just was trying to show that i did do some work to isolate what my issue so the dont think I am just coming here for a hand out but I appreciate your help thanks

Comment: I posted my code not all of it but the part you should need i would think i have my details class listed my constructor and also my DB class with the code thanks again

Comment: @Karl, you are checking if the field `MiddleName` is null then grabbing `STARTINGDATE`, also you probably need to inverse the check.

Comment: @BobVale - yes, thanks, it was quick copy and paste from code I had elsewhere. Updating now.