# "Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values." on DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to populate a model field with a nullable DateTime field from a MySQLReader object. When I try to read it as null instead of it throws

> Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.

I have tried using this code to stop that happening as I had a quick google before asking but this is the only thing I could find, but it throws a couple errors in the IDE:

```
model.repairDate = rdr.IsDBNull("repairdate") ? null : (DateTime?) rdr.GetDateTime("repairdate");
```

What else would I be able to do to prevent it throwing an error?

Comment: *"...but it throws a couple errors in the IDE"* - what are *those* errors? Note that `IsDBNull` requires the column index, which can be retrieved using the reader's `GetOrdinal` method.

Comment: I believe this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489960/nullable-datetime-with-sqldatareader/17490905