# How can I detect if a SqlDataReader result set is the object I am expecting?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have the following code:

```
const string QUERY = "SELECT MAX(Date) FROM table";
command = new SqlCommand(QUERY, _connection);
SqlDataReader result = command.ExecuteReader();
```

This function works as expected. `result` will contain either a DateTime that I care about, or a null non-DateTime object.

What I am trying to achieve is the following:

```
DateTime mostRecentDate = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);
if (/*result is a datetime*/) mostRecentDate = result.GetDateTime(0);
```

But for all the proposed solutions, there is a case where this breaks when either the table is empty, or behaves unexpectedly when it is populated.

EDIT: The approaches I have tried include using `result.HasRows`, `result.Read()`, both of those are bad because the output will always contain 1 row. It will be either a DateTime I want or a null non-DateTime I do not want. What I am asking is if there is an easy way to determine if the `result` was generated as a result of querying against a populated table, or is the null that seems to be generated when I query against an empty table.

[image]

Comment: well first of all I would check to make sure the column name is truly named `Date` and if so since that's a reserved work why not change the query to something like this `SELECT MAX([Date]) FROM table` and show the exact name of the table I doubt the name of your table is named `table` if you are truly not sure then cast the table column name using the `AS` key word

Comment: The statement as posted will never have a column name. Just execute it in SSMS to see that. I'm unclear on what problem you have and how to help you.

Comment: The table is being read in correctly. The query is working as expected. If the table is populated, then the result set is the maximum date entry from the appropriate column. If the table is empty, the result set contains one null of some non-DateTime data type. I am asking how I can create a conditional wherein I can assert that the value returned is in fact a DateTime, and if it is, I will then set the `mostRecentDate` to that DateTime.

Comment: This query will always return exactly one column of a fixed date and/or time data type (the type that `Date` has). The schema never changes in response to the data you get. It is fixed at query compilation time. You must be misinterpreting what you are seeing. How did you find out that the data type is different from what you expected?

Comment: Even having changed to name of the parameter to `date_registered` or `date_valid`, I still get the same general error, it always returns one row with one column. I've switched to SQL Server Management for quick visuals, will edit the question with the results of queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easiest approaches would be an implementation of `ToString()` to the column, once it is a `string` it will be incredibly easy to manipulate.  Simply because you'll have access to all the `DateTime` functionality that is built into .Net.

- `DateTime.ParseExact`
- `DateTime.Parse`
- `DateTime.TryParse`
- `DateTime.TryParseExact`

So the approach I would do would be:

```
using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
     while(reader.Read())
     {
          if(reader[@"Date"] != DBNull.Value)
          {
              string dbDate = reader[@"Date"].ToString();
              DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(dbDate);
          }
     }
```

Obviously you'd have a `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, or a `Query/Stored Procedure` before it would actually work, but this approach should achieve a quick successful grab of the date item out of the database.

You could always check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052753/how-to-parse-nullabledatetime-from-a-sqldatareader/8052819#8052819). They have another approach which can also handle `Nullable DateTime` from the `SqlDataReader`.

Comment: My question's wording was unclear, apparently, but this is what I was looking for, in particular `result.GetValue(0) != DBNull.Value`

Answer (score 1):

Global aggregates always return one row even when the underlying data set is empty. Either pull one row from the data reader and check it for `NULL` (using one of the common methods of doing that). Or, use a local aggregate:

```
SELECT MAX([Date])
FROM (
    SELECT GETUTCDATE() AS [Date]
    WHERE 0=1
) x
--vs.

DECLARE @dummy INT
SELECT MAX([Date])
FROM (
    SELECT GETUTCDATE() AS [Date], 0 AS Dummy
    WHERE 0=1
) x
GROUP BY Dummy
```

The first one returns one row with a `NULL` value. The second one returns zero rows.

Answer (score -2):

If there is a result set, you can check if the column is equal to `DBNull.Value`

```
if (reader.GetValue(0) != DBNull.Value)
{
  var date =  reader.GetDateTime(0);
}
else {

  var date =  new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You may want to use DateTime.TryParse()